# why can i update view from another thread in android?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a code:

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        btn.setText("Test");
    }
}.start();
```

This code works. But if I let `sleep(2000);` then throw error

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        btn.setText("Test");
    }
}.start();

// =>> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

So can someone tell me what is the reason for this difference? I understand that updating UI from another thread is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can update UI tread only in Main tread. You need to call `btn.setText("Test");` only in Main thread. For such behavior you need to use `Handler` and `Looper`.

1. Create runnable with `btn.setText("Test");`.

```java
    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            btn.setText("Test");
        }
    };
```

2. Create Handler with Looper of Main thread.

```java
    Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

3. For udpdate UI need to to call `mainHandler.post(myRunnable)`

```java
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: I understand you. But I tried updating it in another thread like the first code but it still works. I want to know why it is still running without error message ?. thank you.